# About an Image Gallery example in Xcode 4.3 with storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.3

Hello well I'm trying to make an image gallery un Xcode 4.3 with storyboards its part of a tab bar project, in this project i have 3 sections, home, Photos and Video, I tried so hard to make the image gallery but so far I without success so I'm asking you guys if someone  has an example that i can use i really need it for my school and Im.. as you can see a real newbie in Xcode

Thank all of you.